# Cart expands on hover, only on some pages (Magento)

Tags: jquery, css, magento, hover

I have a Magento webshop, and there is an issue with the cart popup/expansion on mousehover.

The cart in the top right corner, is supposed to expand on hover, and it does - but only on some pages.

It works correctly on the product list, homepage, etc. But on product pages it doesn't expand for some reason.

The webshop is http://www.istol.dk/

Anyone who can help?

See this picture:
http://goo.gl/OuLTWC

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: There are errors in console if you look on product detail page. Either there is some js missing or it may be because of error that event does not bind correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I can see the error in the console, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You have a console error on the product pages: `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).superfish is not a function`. My guess is you need to include superfish.js, or make sure the path to it is correct.

Comment: The error is because of the sequence of JS files you have included, if you replicate same sequence as home page has it will most likely fix the issue, try using this sequence 1. jquery-1.7.min.js   2. jquery.prettyPhoto.js 3. superfish.js. In product detail page sequence of JS is different and top menu is also not working.

Comment: The path to superfish.js seems correct. And I have checked the sequence of the js files - it's the same on the product page, as the other sections? http://goo.gl/MtXlso